# Convert tracked changes to highlighted

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, microsoft-word-2010

I am looking for an automated way to convert tracked changes in Microsoft Word 2010 to highlighted text. So, in essence what I'd like to do is:

1. Highlight all text fragments with tracked changes
2. Accept all tracked changes (there is a button for that)

Is there a way to do this either using built-in features or scripting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the [Revisions Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821680(v=office.15).aspx) in VBA. From there it's simple to iterate through each revision item, accept and hightlight it with a predefined color.

Additionally we need to temporarly disable tracking.

```VBA
Sub tracked_to_highlighted()           
    tempState = ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions
    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False    
    For Each Change In ActiveDocument.Revisions        
        Set myRange = Change.Range
        myRange.Revisions.AcceptAll
        myRange.HighlightColorIndex = wdGreen            
    Next    
    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = tempState
End Sub
```

Comment: Great! This does exactly what I wanted. This page has colour names, in case someone wants a different highlight colour: http://word.tips.net/T000253_Changing_Character_Color.html

Answer (score -1):

Strange enough this does partly the job in my documents (Word 2010). The revisions are only highlighted from page 5. Haven't got a clue how to tell the macro to start from the top of the document, not even by

```
Selection.Homekey Unit:=wdStory
```

Manual accept every change does however consider the revisions on pages 1-4 as well.

Anybody similar experiences?

Peter

Comment: If you have a queston, you should one, questions should not appear in answers to other people's questions.